# How to set a tab listener to an ActionBar

Tags: android

i'm trying to do a Tab Layout on android, and i'm trying to add tab ton the action bar but its not working. My probleme is that in this step of the function `setTabListener((android.app.ActionBar.TabListener) actionBar));`, the error log said that `cannot be cast to android.app.ActionBar$TabListener`. I have already set `setTabListener(this)` but `this` in my function refere to the Fragment and i don't know why.

**This is my whole function :**

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_clubs_pagesn, container, false);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    //actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBarNAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener((android.app.ActionBar.TabListener) actionBar)); }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });

    return v;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .setTabListener((android.app.ActionBar.TabListener) actionBar)

is wrong because `actionBar` dose not implement `listener`, you must implement the`listener` in your `fragment` or in your `activity` and then call for example in your fragment:

```
setTabListener(this);
```

for example this is sample code for `activity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    ViewPager viewPager=null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ActionBar actionBar=getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        addTabs(actionBar);


        }
    private void addTabs(ActionBar actionBar)
    {
        ActionBar.Tab tab1=actionBar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("Tab 1");
        tab1.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab2=actionBar.newTab();
        tab2.setText("Tab 2");
        tab2.setTabListener(this);

        ActionBar.Tab tab3=actionBar.newTab();
        tab3.setText("Tab 3");
        tab3.setTabListener(this);

        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
        actionBar.addTab(tab2);
        actionBar.addTab(tab3);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
}

}
```

Update:

```
for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(YourFragment.this); }
```

Comment: Thanks, but my Fragment already implements ActionBar.TabListener

Comment: so use `.setTabListener(YourFragment.this);`