# setTabListener error when applying action bar navigation

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am following up this tutorial about [Android action bar tabs swipe views](http://www.feelzdroid.com/2014/10/android-action-bar-tabs-swipe-views.html).

I have error on the below code

```
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
        }
```

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26116299/how-to-set-a-tab-listener-to-an-actionbar) the mentioned a solution but  I already did it.

this is my code

```
 private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private android.app.ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games", "Movies" };

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search);

         ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            actionBar = getActionBar();
            mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

            for (String tab_name : tabs) {
                actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener((TabListener) this));
                }
    }
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @bharat The ertor be cast to android.app.ActionBar$TabListener... exzactly on this function setTabListener(this); .. what i am doing wrong

Comment: are you using support-v7 library?

Comment: @bharat Yes I guess so , if I go into my sdk , I see it installed , and on the eclipse on left tree I see support v7,  should I do something more ?

Comment: @bharat anyway ill check it

Comment: remove this `(TabListener)` code  from `setTabListener`, if you are extending `ActionBarActivity` then use  `actionBar = getSupportActionBar();` and import all classes of v7 packages.

Comment: @bharat ok ill try it then ill get back to you .. thank you